# Is there a way to Pointer Reference another object in firebase, instead of storing data twice.?

Tags: firebase, rest-firebase

I have a firebase DB with branches for things like:

```
/Customers/{CustomerID}/{CustomerName}
                        {CustomerAddress}

/Contacts/{CustomerID}/{contactID}/{ContactName}
                                   {contactPhone}
                                   {contactEmail}


/sampleout/{customerId}/{sampleoutID}/.....
other Data including the customer name, contact etc etc that is kept above.
```

I am looking for the best way to reference the Customer and the contact information with out: 1)storing it twice in FB tree.   2) making 2 or more read calls.

So I want to be able to read the /sampleOut tree and as it reads say sampleID 1 and it points to a given customer,  it also pickups that customer object, with out having to create a "read" call in my code.

Comment: I too am looking for an answer